# Can SQL Server 2008 use a variable in a WHERE IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Are there any updates in SQL Server 2008 to allow a variable for the `IN` clause of a `WHERE` predicate?

Will this code work as expected?

```
declare @InParams varchar(100) = '1,2';

select * from Category
where CategoryID in @InParams;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See here: [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)  (pick your version), or here http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 5):

No - still need to use either:

- a split function, Table Valued CLR or Table Valued function
- dynamic SQL